# some css not working

Tags: html, css

So I have been following this tutorial for making a calendar widget with html, css, and js but I am stuck on the CSS not working. Did I miss something or miss-type? Where is my html/css going wrong to not end up the same final result? When I try to edit certain CSS it doesn't seem to affect the output.

The tutorial is [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-beautiful-calendar-widget--net-12538) for reference to how it is suppose to look like.

Here is my HTML:

```css
#cal {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin: 50px auto;
  font: 13px/1.5"Helvetica Neue", Helvatica, Arial, san-serif;
  display: table;
}
#cal .header {
  cursor: default;
  background: #cd310d;
  background: -mozlinear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d));
  height: 34px;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0 #87260C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cal .header span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 34px;
}
#cal .header .hook {
  width: 9px;
  height: 28px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ececec;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right top, #fff, #827e7d);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#827e7d);
  box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
.right.hook {
  right: 15%;
}
.left.hook {
  left: 15%;
}
#cal .header .button {
  width: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
#cal .header .left.button {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ae2a0c;
}
#cal .header .right.button {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ae2a0c;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
#cal .header .button:hover {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d94215, #bb330f);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from (#d94215), to(#bb330f));
}
#cal .header .month-year {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#cal table {
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#cal td {
  color: #2b2b2b;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  cursor: default;
}
#cal #days td {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
  color: #9e9e9e;
}
#cal #days td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
#cal #cal-frame td.today {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff inset;
}
#cal #cal-frame td:not(.nil):hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #6C1A07 0px -1px;
  background: #CD310D;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d));
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span {
  font-size: 80%;
  position: relative;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span:first-child {
  bottom: 5px;
}
#cal #cal-frame td span:last-child {
  top: 5px;
}
#cal #cal-frame table.curr {
  float: left;
}
#cal #cal-frame table.temp {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="cal">
  <div class="header">
    <span class="left button" id="prev"> &lang; </span> 
    <span class="left hook"></span> 
    <span class="month-year" id="label"> June 2010 </span> 
    <span class="right hook"></span> 
    <span class="right button" id="next"> &rang; </span>
  </div>
  <table id="days">
    <tr>
      <td>sun</td>
      <td>mon</td>
      <td>tue</td>
      <td>wed</td>
      <td>fri</td>
      <td>sat</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="cal-frame">
    <table class="curr">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
          <td class="today">11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
          <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
          <td class="nil"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific and tell us exactly what CSS rules aren't being applied. Otherwise we'd need to guess.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Well there is a lot really...for starters the text #days table is supposed to be transformed to capitalized and a different color. The text in the header is suppose to be centered as well as the hooks. There's a lot really. But let's start with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I couldn't understand what is you actual query.
But the [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-beautiful-calendar-widget--net-12538) you are referring is having a perfectly working CSS and HTML.
Plus the JS is also working.

The difference I found in the code you have provided are :-

**Within the HTML:-**

```
     <table id="days">
           <td>thu</td>  <!-- Is missing -->
```

**In the CSS :-** (*Use the below CSS totally*)

```
body { 
    background: #e0e0e0; 
} 

#cal { 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
    margin:50px auto; 
    font: 13px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvatica, Arial, san-serif; 
    display:table; 
}
#cal .header { 
    cursor:default; 
    background: #cd310d; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d)); 
    height: 34px; 
    position: relative; 
    color:#fff; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-shadow:0px -1px 0 #87260C; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
} 
#cal .header span { 
    display:inline-block; 
    line-height:34px; 
}
#cal .header .hook { 
    width: 9px; 
    height: 28px; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom:60%; 
    border-radius:10px; 
    -moz-border-radius:10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:10px; 
    background:#ececec; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right top, #fff, #827e7d); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(#fff), to(#827e7d)); 
    box-shadow:0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65 ); 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65 ); 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65 ); 
} 
.right.hook { 
    right:15%; 
} 
.left.hook { 
    left: 15%; 
}
#cal .header .button { 
    width:24px; 
    text-align:center; 
    position:absolute; 
} 
#cal .header .left.button { 
    left:0; 
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px; 
    border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
    border-right:1px solid #ae2a0c; 
} 
#cal .header .right.button { 
    right:0; 
    top:0; 
    border-left:1px solid #ae2a0c; 
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px; 
    border-top-right-radius: 5px; 
} 
#cal .header .button:hover { 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d94215, #bb330f); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d94215), to(#bb330f)); 
}
#cal .header .month-year { 
    letter-spacing: 1px; 
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
}
#cal table { 
    background:#fff; 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
} 
#cal td { 
    color:#2b2b2b; 
    width:30px; 
    height:30px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    text-align:center; 
    border:1px solid #e6e6e6; 
    cursor:default; 
} 
#cal #days td { 
    height:26px; 
    line-height: 26px; 
    text-transform:uppercase; 
    font-size:90%; 
    color:#9e9e9e; 
} 
#cal #days td:not(:last-child) { 
    border-right:1px solid #fff; 
}
#cal #cal-frame td.today { 
    background:#ededed; 
    color:#8c8c8c; 
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 0px #fff inset; 
} 
#cal #cal-frame td:not(.nil):hover { 
    color:#fff; 
    text-shadow: #6C1A07 0px -1px; 
    background:#CD310D; 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #b32b0c, #cd310d); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#b32b0c), to(#cd310d)); 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px; 
}
#cal #cal-frame td span { 
    font-size:80%; 
    position:relative; 
} 
#cal #cal-frame td span:first-child { 
    bottom:5px; 
} 
#cal #cal-frame td span:last-child { 
    top:5px; 
}
#cal #cal-frame table.curr { 
    float:left;      
} 
#cal #cal-frame table.temp { 
    position:absolute; 
}
```

**Screenshot :-**
[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thanks! I must have missed something. Sorry about the weird question. Tried to phrase it the best I could. But this worked perfect! I'll have to check the differences to see where I went wrong.